# ACF Repeater Field on Product Variations

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

Using the following code to add ACF to individual product variations as per [here](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/custom-fields-on-woocommerce-product-variations/) and [here](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/acf-on-product-variations-almost-works/). Everything seems to be displaying properly, except for a repeater field:

```
// Add product variations ACF rule
add_filter('acf/location/rule_values/post_type', 'acf_location_rule_values_Post');
function acf_location_rule_values_Post( $choices ) {
    $choices['product_variation'] = 'Product Variation';
    return $choices;
}

$GLOBALS['wc_loop_variation_id'] = null;

function is_field_group_for_variation($field_group, $variation_data, $variation_post) {
    return (preg_match( '/Variation/i', $field_group['title'] ) == true);
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', function( $loop_index, $variation_data, $variation_post ) {
    $GLOBALS['wc_loop_variation_id'] = $variation_post->ID;

    foreach ( acf_get_field_groups() as $field_group ) {
        if ( is_field_group_for_variation( $field_group, $variation_data, $variation_post ) ) {
            acf_render_fields( $variation_post->ID, acf_get_fields( $field_group ) );
        }
    }

    $GLOBALS['wc_loop_variation_id'] = null;
}, 10, 3 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', function( $variation_id, $loop_index ) {
    if ( !isset( $_POST['acf_variation'][$variation_id] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $_POST['acf'] = $_POST['acf_variation'][$variation_id];

    acf()->input->save_post( $variation_id );
}, 10, 2 );

add_filter( 'acf/prepare_field', function ( $field ) {
    if ( !$GLOBALS['wc_loop_variation_id'] ) {
        return $field;
    }

    $field['name'] = preg_replace( '/^acf\[/', 'acf_variation[' . $GLOBALS['wc_loop_variation_id'] . '][', $field['name'] );

    return $field;
}, 10, 1);
```

When adding a row on the repeater field, it does not appear.

Then I get the following javascript error upon product save, repeated for however many times I click "Add row":

> An invalid form control with
>   name='acf_variation[37][field_5db9a1722bbe2][field_5db9a1de2bbe5][acfcloneindex][field_5db9a1ed2bbe6]'
>   is not focusable.

When I inspect only one table row is there, with `class="acf-row acf-clone"`. ACF's stylesheets show:

```
.acf-repeater .acf-row.acf-clone {
    display: none !important;
}
```

When I add admin styles:

```
.acf-repeater .acf-row.acf-clone {
    display: table-row !important;
}
```

the first field displays but other fields still do not get added (both in display and to the DOM while inspecting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add script after rendering the field:

```
function rdv__after__render_field( $field ){
    //add these if you want to apply it on certain fields only 
    //if ($field['key'] != 'field_key') {
    //    return;
    //}
    echo "<script>
            (function($) {
                acf.doAction('append', $('#post'));
            })(jQuery);
          </script>";
}
add_action( 'acf/render_field/type=repeater', 'rdv__after__render_field', 10, 1 );
```

and then change your 'woocommerce_save_product_variation' (got this piece on https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/acf-on-product-variations-almost-works/) to

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', function( $variation_id, $loop_index ) {
    if ( !isset( $_POST['acf_variation'][$variation_id] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['acf_variation'][$variation_id] ) && is_array( $fields = $_POST['acf_variation'][$variation_id] )  ) {
        foreach ( $fields as $key => $val ) {
            update_field( $key, $val, $variation_id );
        }
    }

}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved the item repeater display issue, but they are still not saving. Getting an endless spinning wheel and POST https://WEBSITE/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error) in the console.

Comment: @user2521295 please see updated answer above. and you're welcome

Comment: YES! Slam dunk. That solved the saving. However now, for some reason, I'm getting "Validation failed. 6 fields require attention" on all products when clicking "Update" at the top, but no fields are highlighted. This is happening for both variable and simple products. Any ideas?

Comment: EDIT: This is happening for new products as well-- saying 3 fields require attention.

Comment: UPDATE: SOLVED! This was happening for new products as well-- saying 3 fields require attention. It looks like the rdv__after__render_field needs to have that "add these if you want to apply it on certain fields only" part active (at least if there are other custom fields on the page, haven't done a full test). Thank you so much!